# Display multiple image in image view

Tags: android

I'm currently working on a calender project, in that i want to display multiple images in imageview, that images that i have to display stored in asset and there(image) refrences stored in sqlite database we have to match the image and display the image in imageview.

Comment: sorry i'm not quite sure i understand your question

Answer (score 0):

One way to this use Canvas. Draw all the images you want on the canvas and then finally draw all the canvas data on a bitmap and set it in on the image view.

OR

You can also use multiple ImageViews and them programmatically as per your need. for eg:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
view.addView(iv);
```